# UFW blocks port 8443 when I explicitly allow it

Tags: firewall, ufw

For whatever reason, whenever I turn on ufw, it **blocks** access to port 8443/tcp even though I have it explicitly allowed. For example:

```
[root:test:~/test]# ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 8443                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 8443 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Based on this rule, I should be able to access to port 8443/tcp. I'm listening on 8443/tcp on SSH:

```
[root:test:~/test]# netstat -antp | grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      763/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19880/systemd-resol
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2456/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1276/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      2456/sshd
```

So with this being said, every time I **enable** ufw, my SSH connection drops. The only way I can get back on it is by accessing the UI console from within Digital Ocean and **disabling** ufw.

Any idea why this could be happening? This is extremely mind puzzling.

Comment: Did you reload `ufw` after making your config changes?

Comment: I did not. That may be what was tripping things up. Thanks. Will try that.